# How to differentiate a rails / devise login if it is made by providing password or via cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It seems the most close method is to hook the devise model User to override  after_database_authentication method.

But within that model method I was unable to send a flag to the controller which handles the root route. (Somehow current_user could not reach atr_accessor enabled parameter).

So wrapping up, what is the most rails way to differentiate devise authentication, if it is made by providing a password or if it is made by a cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rails MVC model the model is not session aware. Your User model thus does and should not know if there is signed in user.

If you want to differentiate from when the user is redirected from the sign in vs other hits on the root path you can set a value in the session:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' } 

# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do
      session[:just_signed_in] = true
    end
  end
end

# this would be whatever controller you have that handles the route path
class HomeController 
   after_action :cleanup!

   def index
      if session[:just_signed_in]
        # ...
      else
        # ...
      end
   end

   private

   def cleanup!
     session.delete(:just_signed_in)
   end
end
```

Another way to do this is by adding a query param to the [redirect path after sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

Comment: Thanks max. Appreciated.